# How to draw a simple line without using Interface Builder in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I want to draw a simple line in view controller with out using Interface builder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I draw a line on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856354/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856354/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-iphone). I know this references InterfaceBuilder, but you can dynamically add your custom view using Obj-C like [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784285/add-uiview-on-uiviewcontroller).

Comment: True, but duplicates should be closed as such, not answered with a link. Once it's closed, a link to the original will appear in the comments anyway, and that helps keep all the answers together in one place. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Sherm. Will flag the original question.

Comment: No worries - it *is* a good answer, and your rep isn't high enough to vote for closing anyway. I gave you a +1 to help with that second problem, at least. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to draw horizontal or vertical line, you can just use UIView.

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<startingX>, <startingY>, <width>, <height>)];
lineView.backgroundColor = <desiredColor>;

//assume self is UIViewController or its sublcass
[self.view addSubview:lineView];
[lineView release];
```